# Pyspark: Grouping by New Column Created by Another Column Resulting in Null

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm looking to find the average closing price per for Amazon but receiving only 1 row with a value of `null` for Year.

What I'm getting with this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import (dayofmonth, hour, dayofyear, month, year, weekofyear, format_number, date_format) 

amazon.withColumn('Year', year(amazon['Date'])).groupBy('Year').avg()['Year', 'avg(Close)'].orderBy('Year').show()
```

```
+----+-----------------+
|Year|       avg(Close)|
+----+-----------------+
|null|1311.457990720811|
+----+-----------------+
```

What I should be getting:

```
+----+-----------------+
|Year|       avg(Close)|
+----+-----------------+
|2012|67.21512003200003|
|2013|75.32051611904767|
|2014|77.32738088888888|
|2015|72.49111121825403|
|2016|69.54706346825398|
+----+-----------------+
```

I tried another identical dataset on the same column and am getting the correct results. I've tried taking the dataset I want over to the Colab notebook that is working on the identical dataset and it doesn't work there, but the code does.

It has to be something in the dataset but the datatype of the Date columns are identical so unsure. Any ideas?

Here's what the dataset looks like:

````
[Row(Date='3/23/2012', Open=192.009995, High=196.199997, Low=191.800003, Close=195.039993, Adj Close=195.039993, Volume=5984000)]```
````

Comment: I tried this with a third and fourth identical dataset and they both resulted in this error: raise converted from None Else: raise. and: Resolved attribute(s) Date#17 missing from Date#48,Open#49,High#50,Low#51,Close#52,Adj Close#53